# Where to get customerId in braintree implementation?

Tags: node.js, braintree

I'm integrating Braintree payments into my iOS app, still on the Sandbox stage. I've pasted Braintree's code into my node.js file on my server with my api keys, but in the following snippet, from https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/node, I don't know where to get 'aCustomerId', or perhaps what to replace it with.

```
gateway.clientToken.generate({
  customerId: aCustomerId
}, function (err, response) {
  var clientToken = response.clientToken
});
```

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure, I work at Braintree. If you have any additional questions, I recommend reaching out to [support](https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact).</sub>

First, if you're not using the [Vault](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/vault/overview), you do not need to pass the `customerId` parameter in your client token generation request. Instead, your request could look something like this:

```
gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, response) {
  var clientToken = response.clientToken
});
```

That will provide you a client token that you can pass to your client to authorize the iOS SDK to interact with Braintree. You can find an example of this in context to a Node.js web app in [this Node example in our Github repo](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_express_example/blob/master/routes/index.js#L54).

If you are using the Vault, then you will need to pass a customer ID as the value for the [`customerId`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/client-token/generate/node#customer_id) parameter. You can obtain a customer ID from the [customer response object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/customer/node) in the [`id`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/customer/node#id) attribute. The response object is provided for every successful Customer API request. For instance, if you are creating a customer, the creation and retrieval of the customer ID would look something similar to this:

```
gateway.customer.create({
  firstName: "Jen",
  lastName: "Smith",
  company: "Braintree",
  email: "jen@example.com",
  phone: "312.555.1234",
  fax: "614.555.5678",
  website: "www.example.com"
}, function (err, result) {
  result.success;
  // true

  result.customer.id;
  // e.g. 494019
});
```

In this example, you could then set the value of the `customerId` parameter to `"494019"`. This would mean your original code could be modified to look like this:

```
var aCustomerId = "494019";

gateway.clientToken.generate({
  customerId: aCustomerId
}, function (err, response) {
  var clientToken = response.clientToken
});
```